# convert Json value into lower case "Uncaught(in promise ) ReferenceError" SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, sapui5

I'm trying to convert Json Value into lower case in SAPUI5.But i'm getting error which is Uncaught (in promise) Reference Error in sapui5. my code is as below.

```
   onInit : function(evt)
    {
      var oModelSamhengiTimeSeris = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("/admin/model/samhengitimeserieswriter.json");                              console.log(this.lowerCase(oModelSamhengiTimeSeris));
    },
    lowerCase: function (obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
     if (typeof obj[prop] === 'string') 
      {
       obj[prop] = obj[prop].toLowerCase();
      }
    if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object')
     {
      lowerCase(obj[prop]);
     }
    }  
    return obj;
    },
```

the Error is when i'm calling lowerCase method from inside the method. is there any other way to convert value into lower case ? or how i can resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe you meant `this.lowerCase(obj[prop])`? It appears to be a method not a plain function.

Comment: i tried that one but not working

Comment: Then please post the entire error message. Also please post a [mcve], your current snippet looks like an excerpt from an object literal and a separate line, please change it so that we can run it.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: lowerCase is not defined

Comment: And what's the error when you try my suggestion?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded(…)

Comment: That suggests it's actually working but the object that you pass in the method contains a circular reference.

Comment: {
 "serviceState": "STARTED",
 "influxConnectionState": "CONNECTED",
 "rabbitConnectionState": "CONNECTED",
 "startTime": "2016-09-15T15:27:22Z",
 "upTime": "23:24:23",
 "valuesReceived": 34550,
 "lastReceiveTime": "2016-09-16T08:17:44Z",
 "lastReceiveSuccesful": true,
 "lastSuccessfulReceiveTime": "2016-09-16T08:17:44Z",
 "lastFailedReceiveTime": "2016-09-16T08:15:55Z",
 "valuesWritten": 34550,
 "lastWriteTime": "2016-09-16T08:17:44Z",
 "lastWriteSuccesful": true,
 "lastSuccessfulWriteTime": "2016-09-16T08:17:44Z"}
 
this is what i'm passing

Comment: I don't get an error with that input. Please [edit] your question to include a complete script that can be executed without syntax errors that throws the exception you have problems with.

Comment: also please don't stick code blobs in comments...update the question itself where you can format them

Comment: I've edited the code.. I hope you will understand now..

Comment: I don't know anything about sapui5, but it seems likely that a `JSONModel` is something else than the object represented by the JSON data. You're not passing the object, you're passing a model instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `lowerCase()` method with your instance of sapui5's [JSONModel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html) class. That instance may contain circular references. You should instead call your `lowerCase()` method with the data *inside* your JSONModel: `this.lowerCase(oModelSamhengiTimeSeris.getData())`.

**But** beware that the JSONModel is loaded asynchronously. So the result of `oModelSamhengiTimeSeris.getData()` will probably be an empty object at the time its called. You can attach to the [requestCompleted](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Model.html#event:requestCompleted) event of the model to do your conversion after the data has been loaded:

```js
onInit : function(evt)
{
  var oModelSamhengiTimeSeris = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("/admin/model/samhengitimeserieswriter.json");
  oModelSamhengiTimeSeris.attachRequestCompleted(function(){
    var data = oModelSamhengiTimeSeris.getData();
    this.lowerCase(data);
    oModelSamhengiTimeSeris.setData(data); //To update bindings
  },this);
},
lowerCase: function (obj) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[prop] === 'string') 
    {
      obj[prop] = obj[prop].toLowerCase();
    }
    if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object')
    {
      this.lowerCase(obj[prop]); //has to be this.lowerCase()
    }
  }  
  return obj;
},
```